# Is filtering an array of objects in mongoDB more performant than getting the entire array?

Tags: mongodb

I'm wondering when it is worth it to reduce the amount of fields requested from mongoDB.

Let's say I have a collection of items that look like this:

```
{
  _id: 'someId',
  list: [{ title: 'a', id: '1' }, { title: 'b', id: '2' }]
}
```

Now if I want to query this collection and just need the titles in the list, should I query it like this:

```
db.items.find({}, { "list.title": 1 });
```

or like this:

```
db.items.find({}, { "list": 1 });
```

I.e. is it worth it to filter the items in the array to just get the subfields I need, or will it take extra time to filter the array?

Comment: Less amount of data, More performant will be the query

Comment: You can (and should) measure this, btw. Don't trust randos on the internet. Trust the numbers.

Answer (score -1):

Of course it's worth it.

According to [MongoDB optimize query performance documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/optimize-query-performance-with-indexes-and-projections/#optimize-query-performance):

> When you need only a subset of fields from documents, you can achieve
>   better performance by returning only the fields you need.

Comment: This is not obvious at all. I don't know how mongoDB stores its data, but if you take any array of objects in JavaScript, and want to filter out properties in that array, you would need an additional filtering step. 

For top-level fields it makes sense, but for nested objects I wouldn't immediately say it's worth it, hence this question.